# C# - Standard Delegates For Simple Or Complex Multithreaded Functions

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, signature

Are there standard delegates in C# that I can just use for invoke. Do I have to declare a new delegate for every new function signature I have to invoke ?

Right now I just have those signatures. But if I can use a native delegate for any complexity of returns and parameters that would be great.

```
public bool isDone()
{...}
public void doStuff()
{...}
public void doMoreStuff(object o)
{...}
public void doEvenMoreStuff(string str)
{...}

// I'm declaring my "custom" delegates like this:
private delegate bool delegate_bool();
private delegate void delegate_void(string line);

// and calling via
if (InvokeRequired)
    Invoke(new delegate_void(doStuff), new object[] { });
else
    {...}
```

---

Edit: Answer seems to be [Action<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) and [Func<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx).

```
if (InvokeRequired)
    return Invoke(new Func<bool>(isDone), new object[] { });
else
    {...}
if (InvokeRequired)
    BeginInvoke(new Action(doStuff), new object[] { });
else
    {...}
if (InvokeRequired)
    BeginInvoke(new Action<string>(doEvenMoreStuff), new object[] { "hello world" });
else
    {...}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Action<>` and `Func<>` delegates are the "standard" delegates that you should use whenever possible.  There are very few situations in which they cannot be used.

In particular if you have optional arguments, `ref` or `out` parameters, more than 16 parameters, or have a `params` parameter then you will need to use another (or your own custom) delegate.

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for the `Action<*>` and `Func<*>` delegates, which do exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

The [Action<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) and [Func<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb549151.aspx) delegates will provide you with what you need

Answer (score 2):

[Action<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) and [Func<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) can perform these types of tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `Action` and a lambda. For example, Dispatcher.Invoke requires a delegate, but we can cast a lambda to Action and therefore do not need to define a new delegate for it:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate() { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

As all have said.  Action and Func will do what you want.  Action should be used on methods that don't return values and you can use Func if a return value is required.